# Android multitouch strange bug when touch point reach limit

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I am make a application on android that need multi-touch gesture! I found that my devices Novo 7 (ainol) supports 5 touch points. I implement onTouch for a View like this

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.i("Touch", "Touch "+event.getPointerCount() + " -- Position " +
                    event.getRawX()+","+event.getRawY());
    }
    else if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP|| event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.i("Touch up","Pointer = "+event.getPointerCount());
    }
    return true;
}
```

At first, everything is ok, the log is printed out perfectly with 5 message. But things happened when i touch and release the 6th point on screen. The log re-printed out 5 message. Can you tell me what is going on here. Sorry for my bad english and if this is a noob question! Thank you very much!

----------- EDITED--------------------

After logging for ACTION_POINTER_UP and ACTION_UP, i found out that when the 6th finger touch (touch down) the screen, all the current pointers (5 pointers) is release from the Event (e.g the action_up and action_pointer_up is call on 5 previous pointers)! Now, the question is, how the android process this situation when the limitation of touch point is reach.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ? and btw android in general the onTouch event is suck and its not 100% works. referring to every single example on the internet all of them got bugs.and btw its not n00b question

Comment: @StyleMe: hi,thank you very much, do you know any work-around for onTouch event? I really need to implement multi-touch for my application! BTW, do you have any IM account, so that we can discuss more in feature.